# objects dissapear when in shading/render

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

am in blender 2.81, and in Shading tab > Rendered, initially the objects in the scene show up fine, i can pan etc, then all of sudden when I zoom in or pan a little more, all the objects disappear, including the world set up. 
I've checked that the visibility of the objects are set to visible as well as am not using a camera view yet so stuck as to why this is happening

Comment: Are you using macOS? Then this could be caused by the bug report [here](https://developer.blender.org/T71147). It has already been fixed, but you will have to wait for the corrective release for 2.81.

Comment: yes, mac with catalina

Comment: Alternatively you could try the most recent [experimental build](https://builder.blender.org/download/) just to test if the issue has been resolved for you as well.

Comment: ah, ok exactly right, sounds like I need to go with the experimental and keep updating every day... thank you :)

Comment: Be aware that the experimental build is, well ... experimental. It may have other issues that shouldn't be present in a proper release.

Comment: understood, rn can't work, so maybe go back to 2.8 or try the experimental, am in rendering and lights, so need to be able to do this lol

Comment: thank you!  :) saved me.